# Check if record exists in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

In `CakePHP 2` I always used `empty` to check if there any result.

```php
<?php
$result = $this->Modelname->find('first', ['conditions' => ['field' => 'value'] ] );
if ( empty($result) ) {
// Bad Request
}
```

In `CakePHP 3` it looks weird to me.

```php
$fancyTable = TableRegistry::get('FancyTable');        
$query = $fancyTable->find()->where(['name' => 'fancy', 'active' => 0]);          

if ( 0 === $query->count() ) {
    // Bad Request
}
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: You can use isEmpty() now, added in CakePHP 3.0.4 ... [see similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30011905)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do:

```
$fancyTable = TableRegistry::get('FancyTable');
$exists = $fancyTable->exists(['name' => 'fancy', 'active' => false]);
```

Comment: how can i use the where condition in exists. like i want to know the existence of an field based upon the two parameters.?

Comment: An update to this answer now that `TableRegistry::get()` has been deprecated. Instead, use: `TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get($table);`

Comment: Cakephp 3.* also you can use this method. `$exists = $tableName->exists([condition]);`

Answer (score 7):

Use something like this:

```
if ($query->isEmpty()) {
    // Query or result set is empty
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was voted down.  It works and doesn't require another query (for exists) that Lorenzo's answer does. I vote it up.

Comment: @cpliu338 possibly because if you do this in conjunction with `first()`, it doesn't work (at least not in the latest Cake). In which case if you still only wanted one record returned, you could just add `->limit()`, and still use this approach.

Comment: @cpliu338 actually the preferred way of checking if `first()` is empty, or exists is it check if the result is null or not. This works better than `limit(1)` in this instance, as `limit` returns a collection.