# Check if object exists or is empty in view template

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

How do you check **within the view template** if the result object contains any entries?

(There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065005/check-if-record-exists-in-cakephp3) already, but this one is slightly different)

Take the [CakePHP 3 blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html) for example. They show how to list all articles on one page:

```
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
public function index() {
  $this->set('articles', $this->Articles->find('all'));
}
```

And the view template:

```
<!-- File: src/Template/Articles/index.ctp -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $article->id ?></td>
    <td>
      <?= $this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', $article->id]) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Disadvantage: **if there are no entries in the database** the HTML table is still rendered.

How can I prevent this and show a simple message like "Sorry no results" insteat?

In `CakePHP 2` I used

```
if ( !empty($articles['0']['id']) ) {
  // result table and foreach here
} else {
  echo '<p>Sorry no results...</p>';
}
```

But since `$articles` is now an object this doesn't work anymore... Is there a new "short way" to check the result object? Or do you usally use another foreach first, like

```
$there_are_results = false;
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  if ( !empty($article->id) ) {
    $there_are_results = true;
    break;
  }
}
if ( $there_are_results == true ) {
  // result table and second foreach here
} else {
  echo '<p>Sorry no results...</p>';
}
```

Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `iterator_count()` function to know if there are results in the set:

```
if (iterator_count($articles)) {
 ....
}
```

You can also use the collection methods to get the first element:

```
if (collection($articles)->first()) {
}
```

**Edit**:

Since CakePHP 3.0.5 the best way to check for emptiness on a query or a result set is this:

```
if (!$articles->isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your hints! All methods work, but the count-method is the shortest code snippet, even shorter as iterator_count. The collection-code needs to be modified a little bit to be useful: `if ( isset(collection($articles)->first()->id) ) { /*render table */ } else { /* no results */ }`

Comment: btw I implemented $query->isEmpty() just for you ;) https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6483 It should be available in CakePHP 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call $articles->count() from your template. (Check for 0)

Comment: This is not the same, though. If $articles is a query, it will do a count query in the database.

Comment: @JoséLorenzo You're right. count() is making a separate SQL query. iterator_count and collection not. So your answer is the better one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have been struggling for a while..

```
if(!$articles->isEmpty()) {
gives error on empty value
Call to a member function isEmpty() on null
<?php if(iterator_count($articles)) { ?>
Argument 1 passed to iterator_count() must implement interface Traversable, null given
<?php if (collection($articles)->first()) {?>
Only an array or \Traversable is allowed for Collection
```

I got 
 
to work, the problem if you render a different view in the controller  $this->render('index');
for a function you should do that after the values has been set