# cake php check if record exist with custom column

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to check if record exist in cake php . I know there is a function .CakePHP 2

```
$this->Notes->id = $id;
if (!$this->Notes->exists())
{
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Notes'));
}
```

but by default it check with the column `id` How can i check with a custom column suppose it is `note_id`. my attemts are [refer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065005/check-if-record-exists-in-cakephp3)

**attempt #1**

```
if (!$this->Noteshistory->exists(['note_id'=>$id]))
{
    throw new NotFoundException(__("Invalid Note "));
}
```

**also tried to set note_id**

```
$this->Noteshistory->note_id = $id;
if (!$this->Noteshistory->exists(['note_id'=>$id]))
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(__("Invalid Note "));
    }
```

but no luck .

Comment: Would be a good idea to look at [the method signature for the methods you're calling](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.8/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2889) - should be obvious that passing `['note_id'=>$id]` won't work (in fact, that would try to find a notes-history record with the id `$id`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[hasAny](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#_hasAny) is the solution -

```
$this->Noteshistory->hasAny(['note_id'=>$id])
```

will return `true` if found else `false`

> **hasAny** is not available in version **3.x**

Comment: I would say hasAny is _a_ solution - a count works just as well, which after all is [all that method does](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.8/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2907-L2915). Note that hasAny doesn't exist in the current version of CakePHP.

Comment: @AD7six . You are right. `hasAny` is not available in `V 3`. `COUNT` will help there.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of: Don't recommend/get-used to using functions that don't exist in a future version - it makes any future upgrade a bit harder. Methods like hasAny don't really help since they just hide that it's a count (personally I don't think I've ever used hasAny), and so were removed. It's not wrong, just an observation+recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `hasAny()`:-https://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Model.html#_hasAny

```
$conditions = array(
    'note_id'=>$id
);
if ($this->Noteshistory->hasAny($conditions)){
    //do something
}
```

Note:- not available in 3.x version