# Check if record exists in database using BuildRules (CakePHP 3)

Tags: sql, database, api, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to check if the ID passed by the user using a HTTP request exists in another table in cakephp. Right now, I tried using :

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn('id_venue', 'venues'));
    return $rules;
}
```

But It doesn't seems to work. This rule is in a reservation table, in this table I have a column called id_venue, I have another table called Venues which has a primary key called id_venue too.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('reservations');
    $this->primaryKey('id_reservation');
    $this->hasOne('Venues');
}
```

I've associated my Reservations table with my Venues table

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did't completly understand the type of call you need but if you just have to check if particular row already exist into the DB you can use **exists**

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('Venues');
$conditions = ['id' => 15];
$exists = $table->exists($conditions); //returns true or false
```

This kind of question was already answered:
[Check if record exists in CakePHP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065005/check-if-record-exists-in-cakephp3)

Comment: That's good but I have to check the id the user pass in the HTTP request using curl for example, in your code the id is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `existsIn` is an array, and I believe the second is case sensitive. Try

```
$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['id_venue'], 'Venues'));
```